# Trigger to increase counter value in table counts twice

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a trigger on table A as follows:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER tr_updatecount  ON tbl_A 
 AFTER UPDATE,INSERT AS BEGIN
 UPDATE tbl_B 
 SET totalupdates = totalupdates+1 
 WHERE siteid IN (select siteid 
                  FROM inserted)    
 END
```

tbl_A has several fields, one of them being siteid and tbl_B has only two fields - siteid and totalupdates

My problem is that for some reason when the trigger is run, the field totalupdates increases by 2 and not by 1.

Comment: Is the trigger maybe triggered twice?

Comment: does your logic performing inserts potentially do an initial insert then update, causing the trigger to fire twice?

Comment: Shouldnt be, this happens even if I run a simple Insert command into the table. In any case I'm not sure how i can check this?

Comment: That wouldn't happen according to the code. What is totalupdates supposed to represent? The total number of update statements or the total number of updated rows? If it is the number of updated rows your trigger is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

most likely you have not considered the possibility of inserted containing more than one row, for example because of multi row updates or inserts.
theoretically "SELECT siteid from inserted" could be returning more than one row.

there is a section in the online help named "Create DML Triggers to Handle Multiple Rows of Data" that you might want to read.

another possibility is that you have another trigger on tbl_B that because of the update also gets executed.